# How to fix TypeError: application_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have code that make instance of class, but occurs an error

> TypeError: application_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a is not a constructor

**index.ts**

```
import Application from 'application-module';

const app = new Application();
```

**application-module**

```
import { IApp, ModuleRoute, IReducerContainer } from 'common-module';

export default class Application implements IApp {
  routes: ModuleRoute[];
  reducers: IReducerContainer[];

  constructor() {
    this.routes = [];
    this.reducers = [];
  }

  addRoute(path: any, component: any) {
    this.routes.push({ path, component });
  }
}
```

`common-module` is just list of an utilitarian classes and interfaces.

Comment: Try to remove `default` in application-module and change import into `import { Application } from 'application-module';`

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak thank you, i tried to rewrite it this way but got the same error

Comment: without `default` you got `TypeError: application_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a is not a constructo`?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak without default i got `TypeError: application_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Application is not a constructor`

Comment: Other thing: When you importing file from source you should use relative path: e.g. `import Application from './application-module';` pls try to import Application in this way

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak `application-module` places at `node_modules`, so there is no reason to use relative path

Comment: Can you say what is `.a` in the built js code?

Comment: @CristianTraìna i think it's order of exported default class. Project built by `creact react-app --typescript` without `eject`, so i don't know clearly what `.a` does mean. Anyway, if i will remove `default`, `.a` replaced to `.Application`

Comment: default import it's pretty much the same, let's skip it now. Syntax `import X from './a' `means you're importing from file `a.ts` from the same catalog, or `import XY from './x/y/'` means you're importing file y.ts from catalog y. Syntax `import angular from 'angular'` it's for import libs from node modules.

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak that's right. And I import lib `application-module` from `node_modules`

Comment: Back to export default. It's pretty convenient to use it when you want to change name during import. When you exporting class it's not good idea to change her name so i suggest to write 'export class X {...` and `import { X } from ...`  but now let's focus on error.

Comment: Ok, thats change a lot. Tell me: what is main file of `application-module` lib (you can check it into package.json) and check if this file contains 'export default class Application`. There is a chance thah you will be forced to do `import * as MpplicationModule from '...'` and run `const app = new MpplicationModule.Application();` or something like that

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak the main file is `build/static/js/main.[hash].chunk.js`. It's minify, obfuscate js code

Comment: Hmmm, and there is any `index.ts` or `src/main.ts` in this node module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190837/discussion-between-przemyslaw-pietrzak-and--).

Answer (score 0):

`application-module` has main `build/static/js/main-[hash].chunk.js` path in `package.json`. To solve my issue we need to change it to `index.js`, but it occur new error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { enhancer } from './store/configureStore';
|
> export class Application implements IApp {
```

Fix it by edit `webpack.config.js`, change `include: paths.appSrc` to `include: paths.appPath` in `ts-loader`.

After that `webpack` can watch my `node_modules`, but it occur an another error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

P.S

So, I'm in a finish line. My webpack config cannot compile `.ts` outside of `src` directory and I decide to compile `.ts` code to `esnext` modules. If connect modules now, all will be done successfully.